# Wrong arguments for 'lrem' command

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to delete an element in a redis list.
This is the error:

> ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'lrem' command

This is the code:

```
client.lrem('eventstore', 1, 'hello');
```

Comment: What are values of `index` and `reply[i]`?

Comment: index is 1 and reply is 'hello'

Comment: the list is 1) hello

Comment: Looks like a valid redis command, indeed. Assuming you are talking to a compatible redis server, the problem must be on node.js side then.